# half-life for electron in excited state

Tags: half-life

Imagine a single atom in which one of its valence electrons is put into an excited state. The electron then decays back into its original state, releasing a photon of a characteristic energy in a random direction. We measure the time between when the electron entered the excited state and when it returned to its original state. We then repeat this experiment many times.  What physical parameters of this system, if any, determine the half-life of the excited state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition probability is proportional to $<\psi_i|\vec r |\psi_f>^2$ in lowest order perturbation.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\vec r$? I would have thought it should be $\hat H$ instead.

Comment: Only the perturbation Hamilton contributes. It contains the EM vector potential, which transforms like $\vec r$ for a plane wave.